# crm using workflow to check IF new records created

Tags: math, sharepoint, workflow, crm

It's end of the day and I have lost all me brain cells. Typical day in the office eh!
Right to the point, We have SSIS process that pushes all data into CRM (2011, on premise).

Time to time the third party service that pushes data into CRM fails and we have to manually push data to their system. However, the only way we find out that there are no new records are created is when someone shuts down!

**Here is the question:**
I thought the solution would be simple. Create a workflow that checks if new records have been created and if not send email. (Don't want to do report as I don't want to run it to check) In SharePoint I was able to create workflow where I can check mathematically. but in CRM I can't.

All i want is to check if count(createdOn) = 0, send email.

Since I am new to CRM I am not sure if I am missing any thing within workflow. I know I can check if value is equal to another value but how do you check if total records is greater then or equal to value? surely, CRM can let you do this without having to manually check every day!!

Answer (score 0):

well you can set the CRM Workflow to run on create but to check the total number of records

you will need to add "custom workflow activity" which allows you to run some code inside the

workflow, inside the workflow activity you will write the code which gets the total number of

records.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know what language I will need to use for writing this custom code?